# How to add plugin with perspective and view to my own RCP app

Tags: eclipse, view, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, perspective

I have a very basic RCP application (e3.7.1) with only one (Hello World) plugin. For reasons of code control I want to develop all perspectives and views in separate plugins. I have now set up one plugin with a perspective and a view. How do I get them into my main RCP plugin, e.g., where do I configure which extensions/extension points? I want the perspective and view to appear in the Perspective Menu as well.

Comment: Can anybody create an example in that you create an RCP app then create an plugin for that RCP app (the plugin will create a new menu or view for the RCP app)? I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you create you RCP application, did you create a .product definition ? did you create a feature ?

Basically Eclipse is based around plugins (OSGI bundles) and you can create view and perspective in different plugins. As long as your plugin is part of you RCP .product definition either as a plain plugin or into a feature definition, you should be able to export your RCP application with all the desired plugins.
If you are just talking about how to run them from Eclipse, you need to edit the run configuration and add all the plugin you need to activate in the Eclipse Application run configuration. This configuration is the on you use to launch the RCP application.

Comment: Yes, I have a .product and the plugins (main and perspective) are (or will be) included in the same feature. So does that mean that I can simply use the perspective and view extensions in my perspective plugin, and when I then put it in the feature together with my main plugin and build, the perpective is runnable? Or accessible from the Perspectives Menu (when I let that show in my main plugin)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The set of view and perspective shortcuts in those menus is specific to *current* perspective.

If the perspective on which you want to make those shortcuts available is your own, then you need to call [`IPageLayout`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPageLayout.html) methods `addShowViewShortcut()` and `addPerspectiveShortcut()` from your [`IPerspectiveFactory`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPerspectiveFactory.html). If you want to make those shortcuts available on someone else's perspective then use [org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_perspectiveExtensions.html) extension point.